# Using constant pointers to avoid includes

Tags: c++, pointers, include, constants, member

My aim is to reduce compile times by minimising includes, while maintaining control over memory allocation within class scope.

**Instanced approach**

*Foo.h*

```
#include "Bar.h" //unneccessary if only number is used in a given source file
struct Foo
{
    Bar bar;
    int number;
};
```

**Constant pointer approach**

*Foo.h*

```
struct Bar; //no include, to use Bar Bar.h must also be included
struct Foo
{
    Bar *const bar;
    int number;
    Foo();
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    ~Foo();
};
```

*Foo.cpp*

```
#include "Bar.h"
Foo::Foo()
 : bar(new Bar()) 
{
}

Foo::~Foo() 
{
    delete bar; 
}
```

Are there any other caveats in using constant pointers like this instead of instance variables? Or perhaps alternative approaches?

Comment: This sort of excessive cleverness will get you in trouble when modules come around. Just include what you need.

Comment: By other caveats do you mean things beyond your totally broken copy constructor and your manual use of `new`?

Comment: Exactly that :) Copy construction isn't necessary for the use case I have so I'm happy deleting them. Have updated the question. Could you expand on 'manual use of new' and how this is an issue compared to any other use of new? Thanks!

Comment: use unique_ptr and save yourself having to use delete.

Comment: You are also trading compile time for run time. Not always the most efficient.

Comment: *"//unneccessary if only number is used in a given source file"* - This is a sign that the class combines too many concerns and should be split up into individual classes.

Comment: Why does `Foo` not just hold a `std::unique_ptr` to `Bar` (or just a plain `Bar` member rather than a pointer)? Then you wouldn't need that manual `delete` in the destructor.  Whenever I see manual memory management like this in a code review I always flag it as a "code smell"..

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly legitimate and standard way to minimize header includes. Indeed, one plausible approach is to always access all private members through an opaque pointer to a struct, so that the public header is just

```
namespace detail {
    struct xxFoo_impl;
}

class Foo {
    detail::xxFoo_impl* xx;
    public:
    // ... stuff ...
};
```

Then, in *Foo.cpp*, `xxFoo_impl` is defined with all the member variables, the constructor allocates `xx` on the heap, and all accesses to the variables are through the `xx` pointer. That way, changes to the private members of the class do not affect any clients of the code: the header is unchanged and they needn't recompile.

So, not only is using pointers to reduce stuff in headers possible, it's even recommended. ;-)

But if users of `Foo` are all expected to be accessing the `Bar` member, then there's no point since they'll all be including `bar.h` anyway.